# How to add wait between urls in scraping python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i want to add wait between scraping these urls. i want to scrape 2 urls every minute so 30 second wait will be enough but don't know how to add wait inbetween urls. newbie here thanks for helping!

```
import cloudscraper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
urls = ["https://www.brandbucket.com/names?page=1","https://www.brandbucket.com/names?page=2","https://www.brandbucket.com/names?page=3","https://www.brandbucket.com/names?page=4","https://www.brandbucket.com/names?page=5"]
for url in urls:
    r = scraper.get(url)
    html = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    titles = soup.find_all("div", class_="domainCardDetail")
    for title in titles:
        print(title.text)
```

Comment: `time.sleep(30)`

Comment: thanks bro but where to add this? which line i mean

Comment: other method is to use some module for `scheduling` - standard module [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html), external module `APSchedule`, etc.

Comment: on Linux popular method is to use service `cron` to run script every 30 seconds. But script would have to remeber in file which urls it has to use in next execution - read this at start, and save new url at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `time.sleep()`

import the time module with
`import time`

then use
`time.sleep("number of seconds you want to wait")`

Comment: thanks alot bro but where to add this? which line i mean should i add it to below "urls" line?

Comment: I think adding time.sleep() at the end of your first for loop should work. So put it at the very bottom of the program. Let me know if that works